# Android M detect if permission dialog is visible

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

How can I determine programmatically if a permission dialog is visible to the user so I know what to do in this case?

Comment: AFAIK there is no clean way to detect permission dialog is visible to screen or not. by hack you can  < take UI dump of screen then find that permission dialog >

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ComponentName cn = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity;
        if ("com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity".equals(cn.getClassName())){
            //permission dialog is displayed
        }
}`
```

`

Comment: I'm a little late but I just tried this and it works! I used to do this using a boolean flag but your solution can also come in handy. Thanks

Comment: Note that getRunningTasks() is now deprecated so this solution may not be viable in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Permission dialog is an activity that is put on top of the activity stack. So when you call for `requestPermission()` method `Activity` implementation asks the `PackageManager` to build intent that will start this activity dialog. This intent has `ACTION_REQUEST_PERMISSIONS` [action](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java).

Probably you need to listen for activity stack changes and check if activity intent has `ACTION_REQUEST_PERMISSIONS` action. I'm not sure if obtaining running tasks will give you this activity listed, because I haven't tried this myself, only to get you going.