# How to find out if LocationPermission dialog is shown currently in app?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-dialog, android-location

I want to ask user for location permission. If I request location permission it will show dialog with `allow` `deny` buttons. I need to know if this dialog is shown in App. Is there any way how to do it?

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235835/android-m-detect-if-permission-dialog-is-visible

Comment: This doesnt work. It is returning my MainActivity as topActivity even if dialog is shown.